# "Rename" ::1 ip to localhost using PHP

Tags: php

I am getting users IP adresses, and I save it in the variable `$user_ip`, now, I am trying to "*rename*" the IP output from localhost (::1) to just "localhost". I've done this with `127.0.0.1`for ipv4 like this:

```
if($user_ip == '127.0.0.1'){
    $user_ip = 'localhost';
}
```

Which works just fine, but when I use colons in an if statement, PHP complains. It won't let me `if($user_ip == ::1){ ...` which I can kind of understand, but I cannot see another way to do this.

Is there a way to do this, or is it simply impossible?

Comment: integers only contain numbers, strings contain everything else, you need to add quotes around that. Also, under what scenario are you retrieving an IP that is returning `::1`?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thanks... Post that as an answer and I'll approve it.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy A webserver sets remote address to `::1` if you access it with `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Only IPv6 I take it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a string encapsulation issue. Make sure when observing integers with other non integers you always treat them as strings.

```
if($user_ip == '::1'){
```

Answer (score 2):

You should make ::1 a string, so that it can be compared to the current IP address. `'::1'`